# how to retrieve the UID from URL in Flutter web app

Tags: flutter

I've developed a Flutter web app that serves as a digital food menu, pulling data from Firestore. The app is working well, and now I'm looking to deploy it on Firebase Hosting.

Additionally, I want to implement a feature where a restaurant's menu can be accessed through a unique link containing the restaurant's UID. The plan is to generate a QR code with this link, and when customers scan it, the web browser should open with the provided link as the address.

I've set up Firebase Hosting, but I'm unsure about the implementation details for extracting the UID from the link and navigating to the appropriate menu page.

This is the code I have tried to extract the UID from the URL.

```
String? getUidFromUrl() {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(html.window.location.href);
  return uri.queryParameters['uid'];
}
```

I call this function inside the Widget build(BuildContext context) of Material app.

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform
  );
  setPathUrlStrategy();
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String? uid = getUidFromUrl();
    return GetMaterialApp(
      theme: ThemeData(
        textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(
          Theme.of(context).textTheme,
        ),
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.deepPurple),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      title: 'SkyPOS Digital Menu',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      // initialRoute: HomePage.id,
      routes: screenRoutes,
      home:uid != null ? ViewMenu(uid: uid) : const HomePage(),
      // initialBinding: AppBinding(),
    );
  }
}

String? getUidFromUrl() {
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(html.window.location.href);
  return uri.queryParameters['uid'];
}
```

Here's what I have in mind:

1. Deploy the Flutter web app on Firebase Hosting.
2. Generate a link containing the UID (e.g.,
   https://example.com/menu?uid=restaurant_uid) from another app.
3. Convert this link into a QR code.
4. When customers scan the QR code, open the web browser with the
   provided link.
5. Extract the UID from the link and navigate to the corresponding menu
   page.

I'm specifically looking for guidance on how to achieve steps 2 and 5 in Flutter web. Any help or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.